# How to align data points and tick labels?

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to draw a grid with circles and label each row and column. While I can draw the data points, I fail to properly align the data points and their respective labels, so the plot looks like this:

[image]

How can it be done correctly, so that the tick labels align with the datapoints?

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from bokeh.models import Circle, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

space = 0.5
row_ind = np.arange(0, 2, space)
col_ind = np.arange(0, 1.5, space)

data_points = list(itertools.product(row_ind, col_ind))

rows = [dp[0] for dp in data_points] 
cols = [dp[1] for dp in data_points]
size = 10
sizes = [size] * len(data_points)
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(columns=cols, rows=rows, size=sizes))

plot = figure(
    plot_width=400,
    plot_height=300,
    x_range=["1", "2", "3"],
    y_range=list("ABCD")
)
plot.circle(
    x="columns",
    y="rows",
    size="size",
    line_color="black",
    fill_color="white",
    line_width=2,
    source=source
)
show(plot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the default ranges from bokeh and change the ticks afterwards using `plot.xaxis.ticker`, `plot.yaxis.ticker` and `plot.yaxis.major_label_overrides`.

**Complete Example**

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from bokeh.models import Circle, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()
row_ind = np.arange(0, 2, 0.5)
col_ind = np.arange(0, 1.5, 0.5)

data_points = list(itertools.product(row_ind, col_ind))
rows = [dp[0] for dp in data_points] 
cols = [dp[1] for dp in data_points]
sizes = [10] * len(data_points)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(columns=cols, rows=rows, size=sizes))
plot = figure(
    plot_width=400,
    plot_height=300
)
plot.circle(
    x="columns",
    y="rows",
    size="size",
    line_color="black",
    fill_color="white",
    line_width=2,
    source=source
)
plot.xaxis.ticker, plot.yaxis.ticker = col_ind, row_ind
plot.yaxis.major_label_overrides = dict(zip(
    [int(i) if i.is_integer() else i for i in row_ind], 
    list('ABCD'))
   )
show(plot)
```

**Output**

[image: Resutl]

Comment: Thanks! I can, however, not reproduce this plot. `row_ind` and `col_ind` need to be switched in your code, I think). When I then use this `major_label_overrides` I get a mix of numbers and letters. I use: `plot.xaxis.ticker = col_ind`, `plot.yaxis.ticker = row_ind` and then `plot.yaxis.major_label_overrides = {i:s for i,s in zip(row_ind, list('ABCD'))}` but that gets me then `0`, `B`, `1` and `D` as tick labels, `A` and `C` are ignored. Could you post your complete code and the version of bokeh you are using? I already upvoted as that gives me something to play with; I accept once it works...

Comment: Ok, solved it; seems to be a bug which is described [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8166). As a workaround I now added `row_ind = [
    int(item) if float(item).is_integer() else item for item in row_ind
]` (same for `col_ind`) which then solves the issue. Did you have a more straightforward solution to this?

Comment: I did not recognize this bug and I created the picture using a self defined dict {0.5:'A', 1:'B', 1.5:'C', 2:'D'} and expected to work the other solution. I updated my answer and show now the complete code. I was not able to avoid the workaround you mentioned.